# How to bind an event twice to a JavaScript plugin

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to call a click event on my plugin inside and outside of the plugin. I mean if I add:

```
clicked: function() { console.log("called from outside"); },
```

as an option to the plugin instance, the plugin will execute its own function, and then call the custom function from the options. Here is the code:

```
(function() {
    // Define our constructor
    this.Test = function() {
        this.options = arguments[0];
    }

    Test.prototype.make = function(){
        this.SelectArea = document.getElementById(this.options.id);
        this.SelectArea.addEventListener('click', function(){
        
            // first execute scripts to this function
            console.log("calling from inside");

            // then execute options clicked function
            this.options.clicked;
        });
    }
}());

var Test = new Test({
    id: 'testId',
    clicked: function(){
        console.log("calling from outside");
    }
});
Test.make();
```

But above code fails, it only fires once. The `clicked` event function from the options is not executing.

Comment: 'Plugin' is vague. Do you think you could clarify a bit?

Comment: it's just a class. I want to encapsulate some functions inside it, OOP-ing it. I thought it could be a plugin in javascript...

Comment: That makes sense. I provided an answer that should be along the lines of what you need. I just wanted to make sure jQuery/AngularJS/BackboneJS wasn't involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.options.clicked;
```

You're not calling the function at all here, you're only referencing it. You need to add parentheses to call it:

```
this.options.clicked();
```

But there's another problem. In the click event callback, `this` is the DOM element, not the `Test` instance. You'll need to save a reference to it, and call it like that:

```
Test.prototype.make = function(){
    this.SelectArea = document.getElementById(this.options.id);
    var clickHandler = this.options.clicked;
    this.SelectArea.addEventListener('click', function(){

        // first execute scripts to this function
        console.log("calling from inside");

        // then execute options clicked function
        clickHandler(); // here
    });
}
```

And, to be even better, you might want to pass on the event variable and DOM context, in case the handler wants to use it:

```
clickHandler.apply(this, arguments);
```

Comment: could you please mention where should I put `clickHandler.apply(this,arguments)` ? thanks.

Comment: In the same place as i had `clickHandler()` in the above snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke the function stored in `this.options.clicked`. I believe this:

```
// then execute options clicked function
        this.options.clicked;
```

Should be:

```
// then execute options clicked function
        this.options.clicked();
```

As `this.options.clicked` is a function. Right now the function is being referenced but the expression is discarded so nothing happens.

Comment: `this` has lost its context -- see my answer.